# Missing conversion is FlinkLogicalJoin: LOGICAL -> STREAM_PHYSICAL

Tags: java, hive, apache-flink

The following exception is encountered when running the flink+hive program:
There are not enough rules to produce a node with desired properties
Missing conversion is FlinkLogicalJoin: LOGICAL -> STREAM_PHYSICAL

I think this is a bug of flink.

Comment: Please share enough information to reproduce the problem and enough of the stack trace that we can figure out where in the code the exception was thrown.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The truth has been established
When looking up the hive dimension table, it must be select *, even if you do not use all the columns, you have to use select *.
I think this is a bug of flink. I don't use all the columns, why do I have to select all the columns when joining?
I would suggest that apache can fix this if it can.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The final solution is: select *